# How to extract Information from Nodes in TreeView in Windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a Winform. I want to show Subanatomy ID information using object of type Subanatomy after the node is selected how Should I do it.?
i have used all the neccessary libraries in my original code [image]

```
`    using System.Windows.Forms;
 using basicObjectLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadTreeItems();
 }

    public void LoadTreeItems()
    {
        // Dummy Data 
        // created a DLL Basic Class Object Conatining class definitions of anatomy subanatomy 
        #region Object
        Anatomy an1 = new Anatomy();
        an1.AnatomyID = 1;
        an1.AnatomyName = "Anatomy1";

        Subanatomy san1 = new Subanatomy();
        san1.SubAnatomyID = 11;
        san1.SubAnatomyName = "subAn1";
        an1.SubanatomyList.Add(san1);

        Subanatomy san2 = new Subanatomy();
        san2.SubAnatomyName = "subAn2";
        san2.SubAnatomyID = 2;
        an1.SubanatomyList.Add(san2);


        Anatomy an2 = new Anatomy();
        an2.AnatomyID = 2;
        an2.AnatomyName = "Anatomy2";

        Subanatomy san21 = new Subanatomy();
        san21.SubAnatomyName = "subAn1";
        san21.SubAnatomyID = 21;
        an2.SubanatomyList.Add(san21);

        Subanatomy san22 = new Subanatomy();
        san22.SubAnatomyName = "subAn2";
        san22.SubAnatomyID = 22;
        an2.SubanatomyList.Add(san22);


        Anatomy an3 = new Anatomy();
        an3.AnatomyID = 3;
        an3.AnatomyName = "Anatomy3";

        Subanatomy san31 = new Subanatomy();
        san31.SubAnatomyName = "subAn1";
        san31.SubAnatomyID = 31;
        an3.SubanatomyList.Add(san31);

        Subanatomy san32 = new Subanatomy();
        san32.SubAnatomyName = "subAn2";
        san32.SubAnatomyID = 32;
        an3.SubanatomyList.Add(san32);

        List<Anatomy> anatomyObj = new List<Anatomy>();
        anatomyObj.Add(an1);
        anatomyObj.Add(an2);
        anatomyObj.Add(an3);
        #endregion

        foreach(Anatomy obj in anatomyObj)
        {
            TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode();
           parentNode = new TreeNode(obj.AnatomyName);

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(parentNode);
            foreach(Subanatomy subObj in obj.SubanatomyList)
            {
                TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
                childNode = new TreeNode(subObj.SubAnatomyName);

                parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
            }
        }


    }
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
        {
            // name of treeNode
            textBox4.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString();
            // to show the ID
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
    }
  }
  public class WindowsFormApplication
  {
    public static void main()
    {
        Form1 _treeviewDemo = new Form1();

    }
 }
}`
```

Comment: When adding anatomy nodes to treeview, put the anatomy object in `Tag` property of the node and use it later. Also you can put the anatomy id in tag and get other information from anatomy list.

Comment: As Reza says, store the ID (or even the entire Subanatomy object) in the tag and then cast it back out in the select event. You should also make use of the TreeViewEventArgs...

Comment: Separate the data from the view and these kind of programming tasks get simple.  The *anatomyObj* variable should be a field in your class, not a local variable, so you can use it later in your event handlers.  Now all you need is the TreeNode.Index property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `TreeNode.Tag` to store your object.

when you create a `TreeNode`, assign the object you want to associate it  with to the `TreeNode`  **Example:**

```
 treeNode.Tag=<object>
```

you can use it later by casting it

**Example:**

```
 (<Class>)treeNode.Tag
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
foreach(Subanatomy subObj in obj.SubanatomyList)
        {
            TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
            childNode = new TreeNode(subObj.SubAnatomyName) { Tag = subjObj.SubAnatomyID  };

            parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        }
```

and get data

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
    {
        // name of treeNode
        textBox4.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString();
        // to show the ID
        textBox2.Text = ((int)treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag).ToString();
    }
}
```

But I think better is

```
foreach(Subanatomy subObj in obj.SubanatomyList)
        {
            TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
            childNode = new TreeNode(subObj.SubAnatomyName) { Tag = subjObj  };

            parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
        }
```

and

```
  private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Action == TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
    {
        Subanatomy suba = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as Subanatomy;
        if (suba != null)
        {
          // name of treeNode
          textBox4.Text = subA.SubAnatomyName;
          // to show the ID
          textBox2.Text = subA.SubAnatomyID.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```